# Does this manipulation in python save more time for my highly inefficient program?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, timing

I am using the following code unchanged in form but changed in content:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from random import seed
from random import randint
import math
from math import *
from random import *
import statistics
from statistics import *


n=1000
T_plot=[0];
X_relm=[0];
 
class Objs:
    def __init__(self, xIn, yIn, color):
      self.xIn= xIn
      self.yIn = yIn
      self.color = color
    def yfT(self, t):
       return self.yIn*t+self.yIn*t
    def xfT(self, t):
       return self.xIn*t-self.yIn*t
xi=np.random.uniform(0,1,n);
yi=np.random.uniform(0,1,n);

O1 = [Objs(xIn = i, yIn = j, color = choice(["Black", "White"])) for i,j 
      in zip(xi,yi)]
X=sorted(O1,key=lambda x:x.xIn)     
 
dt=1/(2*n)
T=20
iter=40000
Black=[]
White=[]
Xrelm=[]        
for i in range(1,iter+1):
     t=i*dt
     for j in range(n-1):
       check=X[j].xfT(t)-X[j+1].xfT(t);
       if check<0:
          X[j],X[j+1]=X[j+1],X[j]
          if check<-10:
             X[j].color,X[j+1].color=X[j+1].color,X[j].color  
       if X[j].color=="Black":
            Black.append(X[j].xfT(t))
       else:
            White.append(X[j].xfT(t))
     Xrel=mean(Black)-mean(White)
     Xrelm.append(Xrel)

plot1=plt.figure(1);
plt.plot(T_plot,Xrelm);
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("Relative ")
```

and it keeps running (I left it for 10 hours) without giving output for some parameters simply because it's too big I guess. I know that my code is not faulty totally (in the sense that it should give *something* even if wrong) because it does give outputs for fewer time steps and other parameters.

So, I am focusing on trying to optimize my code so that it takes lesser time to run. Now, this is a  routine task for coders but I am a newbie and I am coding simply because the simulation will help in my field. So, in general, any inputs of a general nature that give insights on how to make one's code faster are appreciated.

Besides that, I want to ask whether defining a function a priori for the inner loop will save any time.

I do not think it should save any time since I am doing the same thing but I am not sure maybe it does. If it doesn't, any insights on how to deal with nested loops in a more efficient way along with those of general nature are appreciated.

(I have tried to shorten the code as far as I could and still not miss relevant information)

Comment: why is there twice `condn` , one inside the other ?

Comment: Oh that's a different condition. edited thanks

Comment: @azro fixed the errors. please check now

Comment: We cannot really provide guidance on such a hypothetical situation. Depending on what you are actually dealing with, one might be able to optimize the logic, optimize the implementation, or replace the slow parts outright (e.g. replace a loop for numerical computations with a vectorized operation as with numpy). Please [edit] your question to *focus* on a single, *specific* problem. See the [ask] and related pages on guidance; the [MRE] page might apply in specific.

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. You cannot use a random indentation because otherwise the script simply do not run (syntax error). Please use a uniform indentation so it can run. Besides this your code still does not works due to additional errors like using a range with a float parameter. I doubt you tried to run this code.

Comment: At a glance (the code cannot run), it looks like your code is needlessly repeating computations. Most prominently, it keeps on computing and comparing `xfT(t)` - which is actually just a constant key per object scaled with an inconsequential factor. For any two objects, this will always have the same result. Merely storing this should bring considerable speedup. Further possibilities for improvement are ignoring sequences of pairings that did not change, and caching lookups.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The errors came in I think while I was changing the code to put it here and I did not re-run it. But I have now de-bugged it. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @ MisterMiyagi "it keeps on computing and comparing xfT(t) - which is actually just a constant key per object scaled with an inconsequential factor. For any two objects, this will always have the same result" This is not clear. With each time step, it changes. Besides, for each j in X[j] this would be different because there xIns are different. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @Lost For two objects `a` `b`, `a.xfT(t)-b.xfT(t)` is going to be `((a.xIn - a.yIn) - (b.xIn - b.yIn)) * t` – one could pre-compute `a.xIn - a.yIn` or even `(a.xIn - a.yIn) - (b.xIn - b.yIn)` and merely scale that by `t`. Right now you have two method calls and four attribute accesses for what should at most be two attribute accesses. You don't even need to multiply by `t` for the `check<0` comparison, only for `check<-10`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, that should save time when the function is linear in t. But I need to work with other functions also such as cos(t)-sin(t), etc. I don't suppose there is a way to use your idea in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- **the mean is recomputed from scratch** based on the growing array. Thus, the complexity of `mean(Black)-mean(White)` is **quadratic** to the number of elements.
- **The `mean` function is not efficient**. Using a basic `sum` and division is much faster. In fact, a manual mean is about 25~30 times faster on my machine.
- **The CPython interpreter is very slow** so you should avoid using loops as much as possible (OOP code does not help either). If this is not possible and your computation is expensive, then consider using a natively *compiled* code. You can use tools like PyPy, Numba or Cython or possibly rewrite a part in C.
- Note that strings are generally quite slow and there is no reason to use them here. Consider using enumerations instead (ie. integers).

Here is a code fixing the first two points:

```py
dt = 1/(2*n)
T = 20
iter = 40000
Black = []
White = []
Xrelm = []
cur1, cur2 = 0, 0
sum1, sum2 = 0.0, 0.0

for i in range(1,iter+1):
    t = i*dt
    for j in range(n-1):
        check = X[j].xfT(t) - X[j+1].xfT(t)
        if check < 0:
            X[j],X[j+1] = X[j+1],X[j]
            if check < -10:
                X[j].color, X[j+1].color = X[j+1].color, X[j].color
            if X[j].color == "Black":
                Black.append(X[j].xfT(t))
            else:
                White.append(X[j].xfT(t))
    delta1, delta2 = sum(Black[cur1:]), sum(White[cur2:])
    sum1, sum2 = sum1+delta1, sum2+delta2
    cur1, cur2 = len(Black), len(White)
    Xrel = sum1/cur1 - sum2/cur2
    Xrelm.append(Xrel)
```

Consider resetting `Black` and `White` to an empty list if you do not use them later.

This is **several hundreds of time faster**. It now takes 2 minutes as opposed to >20h (estimation) for the initial code.

Note that using a compiled code should be at least 10 times faster here so the execution time should be no more than dozens of seconds.

Comment: "The CPython interpreter is very slow.." Does this mean if I do write this code in Matlab, Mathematica it will be faster?

Comment: Matlab has an integrated JIT so such code will certainly be faster but Matlab also also known pretty slow compared to native code in most cases. I do not know for Mathematica. The JIT of PyPy is pretty fast and should compete with Matlab in such case. Numba/Cython should be much faster but this require in-depth modification (certainly simpler than rewriting everything in Matlab).

Comment: CPython code can be pretty fast when you use built-ins and optimized C libraries. A good example is Numpy. This is why people often avoid such kind of code with loops and prefer a codes that make uses of vectorized functions. In fact, the same thing applies for most relatively high-level language, including Matlab: while loops should be faster than with CPython, matlab is design to be fast for computing vector and matrices with vectorized operations.

Comment: I have never used C or CPython so I am not sure if I can use these. Besides this, what do you mean when you say "consider using a natively compiled code." Python doesn't have a native compiler so do you mean that I should switch to a one that has a native compiler?

Comment: Ok if you never used C before it is certainly better to try PyPy and Numba instead of Cython (or even writing C code). JIT compilers convert bytecode to native code on the fly. [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) is a JIT-based interpreter. It is very simple to use as you just need to change the command line and not your code. However, it does not supports all modules. [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) is a JIT that is used (typically) from a CPython code and more especially mainly for Numpy-based code. It is restricted but it can be very fast as long as you operate on basic vector/matrix/scalar.

Comment: Numba require you to add simple annotations in your code. You may need to tweak it so it works with it. While object-oriented code (OOP) are experimentally supported, this is complex to use and still experimental & restricted. Using non-OOP code is often faster in Python anyway.

Comment: Is there a way I can use Numpy vectorization for any of the loops above? I thought long about it and it seems there is no way around it.

Comment: I am not sure you can only use Numpy vectorized function (Numpy vectorized operation often require the operation on each item to be independent of others), but Numpy+Numba should do the work if Numpy alone is not possible. This require to convert your list-based OOP-code to an array-based code (which is nearly always a good idea in term of performance).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in earlier comments, this one is a bit too broad to answer.

To illustrate; your iteration itself doesn't take very long:

```py
import time


start = time.time()

for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(10000):
        pass

end = time.time()
print (end-start)
```

On my not-so-great machine that takes ~2s to complete.

So the looping portion is only a tiny fraction of your 10h+ run time.

The detail of *what* you're doing in the loop is the key.

Whilst very basic, the approach I've shown in the code above could be applied to your existing code to work out which bit(s) are the least performant and then raise a new question with some more specific, actionable detail.

Comment: To find out which parts are slowing down the program, a profiler is likely more suitable than manually timing arbitrary bits one by one.